# YUI,Javascript: How can i optimize this code snippet to run faster?

Tags: javascript, html, yui, javascript-framework

I am making an application which displays thousands of items on 1 single page according to users query.
I have uploaded a similar code snippet here :

```
http://adiinviter.com/forums/stack/current.php
```

The Code snippet in the file is  :

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.table_head_outer {
  background-color: #7192a8;
  padding: 0px;
    width:100%;

  font-weight:bold;
  color:#ffffff;
  clear:both;
  border: 1px solid #5a7f97;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;

}

.table_head_body {
  padding: 3px 0px 3px 0px;
  background: transparent;
  text-align:left;
  margin-left: 13px;
  margin-right: 3px;
}

.table_body_outer {
  border-top: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    width:100%;
  display:block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
  border-left: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
  border-right: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
}


.table_body {
  padding: 5px;
  background: transparent;
}
.overlayDiv {
    position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; left: 0px;
    background-color: rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.3);    
    font-family: Verdana; z-index: 2000;

}
.popup_box {
    position: relative; opacity: 1;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-width: 0px;  border-style: solid;    border-color: #C1B4B4;
    border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px;    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    width: auto;  height: auto; text-align: center;
}
#optContain {   width: 890px; }
#contentBox {
    text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; 
}

#sectionHeader {    text-align: left; padding: 5px; }
#sectionHeaderRight { padding:5px; text-align: right; }

.sectionFooter { padding: 5px 15px; text-align: right;}

.product_disp, .product_disp_clicked, .product_disp_hover {
    padding: 6px;   width: 250px; height: 50px;
    margin: 5px;    float: left;    overflow: auto; cursor: pointer;
    border-width: 1px;  border-style: solid;    
    border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px;    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}
.product_disp_clicked {
    border-color: #700;
    background-color: #e00;
}
.product_disp_hover {
    border-color: #aaa;
}
.div_trail_img {
    position: absolute; z-index: 2030; visibility: hidden;
    border-width: 1px;  border-style: solid;    border-color: #ccc;
    padding: 5px;   background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;-moz-border-radius: 5px;-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

.prodcuts_img { float:left; 
    margin-right: 5px; 
    height:50px; width:auto;
 }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function adi_onArrive(obj)
    {
        setTimeout(function () { 
                if(obj['data'] != null) 
                    document.getElementById(obj['id']).innerHTML += obj['data'];      
                }, 0);
    }
    function putDimensions()
    {

        document.myForm.sHeight.value = window.screen.height;
        document.myForm.sWidth.value = window.screen.width;
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="trail_img_div" class="div_trail_img" style="">
<img id="trail_img" src=""/>
</div>

<?php


if($_GET['num_products'] == "" && $_GET['get_products'] == "")
{
    ?>

    <center>
    <form action="" method="" onSubmit="return putDimensions();" name="myForm">
    No. of Items : &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="textbox" name="num_products" > <br /><br />
    <input type="hidden" name="sHeight" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="sWidth" value="">
    <input type="submit" name="get_products" value=" Get Products "> 

    </form>
    </center>
<?php 
}
else
{

    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //trail_img_div
    //trail_img
    function click_effect(myObj,event) // onclick
    {
        if(myObj.className == "product_disp_clicked")
        {
            myObj.className = "product_disp";
        }
        else if(myObj.className == "product_disp_hover")
        {
            myObj.className = "product_disp_clicked";
        }
        return true;
    }
    function show_img_trail(img_url,myObj) //on mousemove to div
    {
        if(myObj.className == 'product_disp') myObj.className = 'product_disp_hover';
        document.getElementById('trail_img').src = img_url;
        document.getElementById('trail_img_div').style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementById('trail_name').innerHTML = 'Name : '+myObj.getAttribute('tip');
    }
    function hide_img_trail(myObj) //onmouseout
    {
        trail_img_div = document.getElementById('trail_img_div');
        trail_img_div.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        //trail_img_div.setStyle('visibility','hidden');
        if(myObj.className == 'product_disp_hover') myObj.className = 'product_disp';
    }
    function m_move(myObj)
    {
        if(myObj.className == 'product_disp') myObj.className = 'product_disp_hover';
    }
    function m_out(myObj)
    {
        if(myObj.className == 'product_disp_hover') myObj.className = 'product_disp';
    }
    function update_co_ords(event) // onmousemove to td
    {
        trail_img_div = document.getElementById('trail_img_div');
        if(event.pageX !=  undefined){
            trail_img_div.style.left = (event.pageX + 10)+ 'px';
            trail_img_div.style.top = (event.pageY + 10)+ 'px';
        }
        else{
            trail_img_div.style.left = (event.clientX + 10)+ 'px';
            trail_img_div.style.top = (event.clientY + 10)+ 'px';
        }
    }
    function toggle_all(event)
    {
        conts_container = document.getElementById('conts_contain');
        divArr = conts_container.querySelectorAll('div.product_disp');
        if(divArr.length ==  0) //uncheck all
        {
            divArr = conts_container.querySelectorAll('div.product_disp_clicked');
            for(i=0; i<divArr.length ; i++)
            {
                divArr[i].className = 'product_disp';
            }
        }
        else // check all
        {
            for(i=0; i<divArr.length ; i++)
            {
                divArr[i].className = 'product_disp_clicked';
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    </script>

<table class="overlayDiv" id="popupBox">

<tr>
<td align="center" align="center" valign="middle" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;padding: 10px;">
<center>
<div class="popup_box" align="center">
    <center>
    <table style="width: 870px; border: 1px solid #333;" class="" id="optContain">
    <tr class="">
        <td align="left">
            <div class="table_head_outer" style="position:relative;">
            <div class="table_head_body" id="sectionHeader"> Product Details </div> 
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" class="table_body_outer" style="font-size: 10pt;text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; height: 500px;" id="contentBox">     
        <div style="padding: 10px;"> <a href="" onclick="return toggle_all(event);"> Select All </a> </div>
        <div style="height: 500px;overflow: auto;"  id="conts_contain" onmousemove="return update_co_ords(event);">

        </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="sectionFooter" align="right" style="background-color:#fff;">
            <div align="center" style="margin: 5px 15px;">
                <input type="button" class="button" name="struct_close" id="close_popup" value=" Add Now ">
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </center>
</div></center>
</td></tr>
</table>

<?php 

//   Code to caculate height and width

    $width = $_GET['sWidth'];
    $height = $_GET['sHeight'];
    $sss = intval(($width - 130) / 260);
    $sss = $sss * 260;
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    conts_container = document.getElementById("conts_contain");
    conts_container.style.width = "'.($sss + 120).'px";
    document.getElementById("contentBox").style.width = "'.($sss + 150).'px";
    conts_container.style.maxHeight = "'.($height - 150).'px";
    </script>
    ';

    flush();



    //   Code to Add items in contentBox

    $arr = array('name' => 'Product_', 'id' => 10);
    $status = 'Available';

    for($i = 1; $i <= $_GET['num_products'] ; $i++)
    {
        $someVar .= '<div class="product_disp" 
            onclick="return click_effect(this,event);"  
            onmousemove="return show_img_trail(\'pic.jpg\',this);"      
            onmouseout="return hide_img_trail(this);" align="left" >    <img src="pic.jpg" class="prodcuts_img"/>   
            <span style="overflow:hidden;" align="left"> <b> product_'.$i.' </b>    <br/>
            id : '.rand(0,10000).' <br /></span>
            <span style="padding:0px;width: 100%;" align="right">'.$status.' </span>
            </div>';        
            if($i % 100 == 0)
            {
                $output = array('id' => 'conts_contain', 'data' => $someVar);
                echo '<script type="text/javascript"> adi_onArrive('.json_encode($output).'); </script>';
                $someVar = '';
            }
    }
    if($someVar != '')
    {
        $output = array('id' => 'conts_contain', 'data' => $someVar);
                echo '<script type="text/javascript"> adi_onArrive('.json_encode($output).'); </script>';
                $someVar = '';
    }

}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

The Flow :
    The PHP file first displays the empty structure and releases the output buffer. This will display 
    the structure with no items in it to the client browser, quickly. Then the PHP file sends some 
    javascript funciton calls to add the items in the box(300 at a time.).

Please look into the codes for any optimization or change in code which will help to make it run faster
and solve following issues

1. Slow scrolling : When thousands of items are loaded into the box, it becomes very very slow to scroll 
   the page. I want to know if there are any optimizations/code changes or any other parallel methods to 
   get over this issue.
2. Auto resizing of pop up container window to best fit variable screen sizes by leaving certain paddings 
   on all the sides.  I hope it can be best done in YUI. Here is how i am calculating and resizing window 
   currently

   ```
           $width = $_GET['sWidth'];  
           $height = $_GET['sHeight'];  
           $sss = intval(($width - 130) / 260); // 260 is the width of one item including paddings  
           $sss = $sss * 260;   
           echo '<script type="text/javascript">  
               conts_container = document.getElementById("conts_contain");  
               conts_container.style.width = "'.($sss + 120).'px";  
               document.getElementById("contentBox").style.width = "'.($sss + 150).'px";  
               conts_container.style.maxHeight = "'.($height - 150).'px";  
               </script>';
   ```
3. Select All works quite. Is there any other superior way to speed up that using YUI? here is how its 
   working currently :

   ```
           function toggle_all(event)  
           {  
               conts_container = document.getElementById('conts_contain');  
               divArr = conts_container.querySelectorAll('div.product_disp');  
               if(divArr.length ==  0) //uncheck all  
               {  
                   divArr = conts_container.querySelectorAll('div.product_disp_clicked');  
                   for(i=0; i<divArr.length ; i++)  
                   {  
                       divArr[i].className = 'product_disp';  
                   }  
               }  
               else // check all  
               {  
                   for(i=0; i<divArr.length ; i++)  
                   {  
                       divArr[i].className = 'product_disp_clicked';  
                   }  
               }  
               return false;  
           }
   ```

I have also used facebook like bigPipe concept on that page to pipeline the data but i am not sure 
if i am doing it rite. I mean i am loading thousands of item data on that page so i think it can be 
broken into more structural things. I would really want to know how can i make it much and much faster 
and highly optimized to improve the performance.

Answer (score 0):

With very large tables you'll see a huge improvement in rendering performance by setting `table-layout:fixed` in CSS. This disables the column resizing algorithms that account for the width of every single cell in the table when determining column widths. The side-effect is you need to set your widths appropriately using `col` elements at the top of the table (otherwise the first row controls the column widths).